# How to get equations in align environment to have numbers

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, tags

If I have the following situation

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
y &= 2x+3
y &= 7x+4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The equations in the align environment won't have numbers next to them. Whats the best environment to use so that multiple aligned equations have numbers?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use the `align` environment, not `align*`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard I hope to master Tex someday haha.

Comment: If I want the number say only on the final equation is that possible?

Comment: Use \notag on any line for which you do not want a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply erase the star and equations will get numbered.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
y &= 2x+3 \\
y &= 7x+4
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly as @Bernard said.